# sh on Lion can't cd into folders with implicit paths (causing make to fail constantly)

Tags: macos, bash, osx-lion, make, sh

I've had a problem with my OSX 10.7 Lion install for some time and I finally took some time to investigate.

The issue is that when running `make`, I always get an error of the form:

`/bin/sh: line 0: cd: [folder]: No such file or directory`

This always comes as a surprise because the 'file or directory' is always quite clearly present in the directory and I'm able to `cd` into it with `bash`. I finally had the foresight to launch into `/bin/sh` to try `cd`ing into a local build directory. No surprise, it fails:

`sh-3.2$ make
mkdir .dist
mkdir .dist/mdoc
tar cf - book.css book.ncx book.xml container.xml css/book.css 
external.png full-head.xml full-tail.xml glossary.xml index.sgml [...]
commands.xml | tar -xf - -C .dist/mdoc
( cd .dist && tar zcf ../mdoc.source.tgz mdoc )
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: .dist: No such file or directory
make: *** [mdoc.source.tgz] Error 1
sh-3.2$ cd .dist
sh: cd: .dist: No such file or directory
sh-3.2$ cd ./.dist
sh-3.2$ pwd
/Users/msutherl/src/mdoc/.dist/mdoc/.dist`

It turns out that I cannot specify paths implicitly with `sh`. Indeed I had been fixing Makefile by adding explicit paths everywhere by hand.

Does anybody know where this could come from? Could it be that I modified a `sh` config file somewhere by accident? Could it be a problem with my path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible there is a conflict with `CDPATH`? Try:

```
$ unset CDPATH
```

and then see if `make` works?